# Capturar o link de imagens contidas no html

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$content = '
text text text text <img src="path/to/image/1">text text text text
    <img src="path/to/image/2">
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text <img src="path/to/image/3"><img src$
<img src="path/to/image/5"> ';

$frst_image = preg_match_all( '|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i', $content, $matches );

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Ele está retornando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="path/to/image/1">
    [1] => <img src="path/to/image/2">
    [2] => <img src="path/to/image/3">
    [3] => <img src="path/to/image/4">
    [4] => <img src="path/to/image/5">
)
```

Porém, quero que retorne somente o conteúdo contido dentro de **src**, como faço isso?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887307/getting-href-value-of-from-a-tag

Comment: preciso que seja feito no back-end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só usar o índice correto:

```
print_r( $matches[1] );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xGo4O0)**.

Você usou o índice `0`, que representa o conjunto todo capturado. Os índices de `1` em diante representam os grupos de captura entre parênteses, que é o que você precisa.

Comment: Minha mania feia de complicar as coisas +1

Comment: desatenção minha, cabeça confusa de tanto cansaço. Obrigado

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues foi um bom complemento o seu, pode servir pra coisas mais complexas.

Comment: @Fábio quando for usar `print_r`, pode ajudar testar sem índice, `print_r( $matches );`, assim fica mais fácil ver a estrutura toda da variável.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o [DOMDocument()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) e [simplexml_import_dom()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) realizar um loop buscando pelo atributo src.

**Exemplo:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br><img src=\"myimage.jpg\" title=\"title\" alt=\"alt\"></body></html>");
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');
foreach ($images as $img) {
   echo $img['src'];
}
```

**Saida:**

```
myimage.jpg
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/8B7x9M)

Referencia e mais exemplos: [How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138313/how-to-extract-img-src-title-and-alt-from-html-using-php)